# Remove spacing between rows of a table

Tags: tables, multicolumn, white-space, cell

I need to remove the whitespace between the rows of a table due to the first cell of first column overflowing to more than a line.  See the screenshot the current typset of the pdf.

[image: Screenshot of the current typset of the pdf.]

So I need to remove the whitespace between the bold "Summer Placement at the University of Manchester" and the main body "Worked with Professor Terrance Wyatt..." in the cell below.

Here is my current code:

```
\section{Work Experience}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.12\linewidth}p{0.85\linewidth}}
\textsc{June 2017 - Sep. 2017} & \textbf{Summer Placement at the University of 
Manchester} \\
& Worked with Professor Terrance Wyatt at the High Energy Particle (HEP) Group 
at the University of Manchester on a research project over the summer of 2017.\\
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Well, this space is caused by you as you want a new line and the left column is too high. Use e.g. a parbox to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version using `\parbox`. You real problem is not the spacing between table rows (that's correct as you have a two line high left column), but that you used a new row for something which should be in the same row, just a new line.

[image: table]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} % to make it nearly fit
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\section{Work Experience}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.12\linewidth}p{0.85\linewidth}}
\textsc{June 2017 - Sep. 2017} & \adjustbox{valign=t}{\parbox{.85\linewidth}{\textbf{Summer Placement at the University of 
Manchester} \\
Worked with Professor Terrance Wyatt at the High Energy Particle (HEP) Group 
at the University of Manchester on a research project over the summer of 2017.}}\\
Test & Test
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: why the parbox not just use the existing `p` column (which is a parbox)?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're right, I forgot the par version. I oriented at the `\\ `. Upvoted yours.

Comment: you could use `\newline` rather than a blank line if you wanted a linebreak in a p column without making a nested box

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, got my tables bronze badge with that :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest one of these three layouts, based on `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} % to make it nearly fit
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\scshape}
\renewcommand{\theadalign}{tl}
\newcommand{\nl}{\newline}

\begin{document}

\section{Work Experience}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{0.12\linewidth}X@{}}
\thead{June 2017\\--\,Sep. 2017} & \textbf{Summer Placement at the University of
Manchester} \nl
Worked with Professor Terrance Wyatt at the High Energy Particle (HEP) Group
at the University of Manchester on a research project over the summer of 2017.\\
Test & Test
\end{tabularx}
\vspace{1cm}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{0.12\linewidth}X@{}}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textsc{June 2017\,--\,Sep. 2017}\qquad \textbf{Summer Placement at the University of
Manchester}} \\[1ex]
 & Worked with Professor Terrance Wyatt at the High Energy Particle (HEP) Group
at the University of Manchester on a research project over the summer of 2017.\\
Test & Test
\end{tabularx}
\vspace{1cm}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lX@{}}
\textsc{June 2017\,--\,Sep. 2017} & \textbf{Summer Placement at the University of
Manchester} \smallskip\nl
Worked with Professor Terrance Wyatt at the High Energy Particle (HEP) Group
at the University of Manchester on a research project over the summer of 2017.\\
Test & Test
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The text should be part of the same `p` cell as the bold line so

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} % to make it nearly fit


\begin{document}

\section{Work Experience}
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\dimexpr.15\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}p{0.85\linewidth}@{}}
\textsc{June 2017 - Sep. 2017} &\textbf{Summer Placement at the University of 
Manchester}

Worked with Professor Terrance Wyatt at the High Energy Particle (HEP) Group 
at the University of Manchester on a research project over the summer of 2017.\\
Test & Test
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I borrowed TeXnician's mwe:-)